# Working with different screen sizes and different densities for resource drawables

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I'm preparing drawables for my app. After some research, I came to know that 3 parameters that needs to be considered are Screen-size, Density and Resolution.

**1.)** Since for a particular screen-size, if density varies then corresponding resolution will automatically vary. Also, for a particular density, if screen-size varies then corresponding resolution will automatically vary.

Going by this logic, I removed resolution from consideration and planned to concentrate only on screen-size and density. Am I correct in this approach?

**2.)** Now as per documentation, if you are preparing *100x100* image for *mdpi*, then you should have *75x75* and *150x150* image for *ldpi* and *hdpi* respectively.

So I created an image resource drawable (.png) of size 100x100 with density 160 (mdpi). Then I created the same image with size 75x75 with density 120 (ldpi) and 150x150 with density 240 (hdpi) and placed them in respective drawables folders.

But after doing this, when I run the app on emulators having combination of different screen-size and different densities, the drawables just doesn't fit-in properly in the given space.

In some smaller screen-sizes, 3rd icon is getting cut halfway through.

Am I doing something wrong?

Any help appreciated.

Refer this: [image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you using seperate drawable folders, like `drawable-hdpi`?

Comment: Orientation can be an important factor too ;)

Comment: @crocboy : Yeah, I'm using `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi` and a default `drawable` folder

Comment: @StefandeBruijn : I have locked the app for Portrait only

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your images in res/drawable folder by convention.

In res folder there could be more than one drawable folder like res/drawable-ldpi, res/drawable-mdpi, res/drawable-hdpi, res/drawable-xhdpi, and res/drawable-tvdpi.

You might be creating an app for different phones with different screen resolutions and screen sizes.

Android have a categorization of phone screens according to the dpi of the screen, namely ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, tvdpi (low, med, high, xtra high, tv respectively).

Your goal is to add each copy of images to these folders for each type of your target devices. For that you have to resize your images in the dpi ratio.

3:4:6:8 is the default dpi scaling ratio

[More](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: I have already done that. As mentioned in the question itself, I'm creating 3 versions of same image resource and placing them into `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi` and `drawable` folders. But it still doesn't work properly as mentioned in question and attached screenshot.